# How to iterate through table using selenium?

Tags: selenium-rc

I have  a table called UserManagement that contains information about the user.This table gets updated whenever new user is created. If i create two users then i need check whether two users are actually created or not.   Table contains ID,UserName,FirstName,LastName,Bdate..ctc. Here ID will be generated automatically.
                  I am running Selenium-TestNG script.Using Selenium,how can i get the UserName of the two users which i have created? Should i have to iterate through table? If so how to iterate through the table?

Answer (score 2):

Use ISelenium.GetTable(string) to get the contents of the table cells you want. For example,
  `selenium.GetTable("UserManagement.0.1");`
will return the contents of the table's first row and second column. You could then assert that the correct username or usernames appear in the table.

Comment: I tried the same using it in a loop as selenium.GetTable("UserManagement.i.1") where I want to iterate through loop but it wont work..instead selenium.GetTable("UserManagement.0.1") it works..ANy idea why

Comment: @sam what values of i are you iterating over?

Comment: following is what I am trying to do
i is a counter to numof rows. 
For i As Integer = 1 To NumOfRows
Dim strTableColumn As String = selenium.GetTable("Group.i.1")
If (strTableColumn = pword) Then
                    ReturnValue = i
                    IsFound = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next

Comment: @sam looks like you have 2 issues: you're starting at 1 instead of 0 and you need to use string concatenation to build the locator `"Group." + i + ".1"` instead of `"Group.i.1"`

Answer (score 1):

Get the count of rows using Selenium.getxpathcount(\@id = fjsfj\td\tr") in a variable rowcount

Give the columncount in a variable

Ex:

```
int colcount = 5;
```

Give the req i.e New user

```
String user1 = "ABC"

for(i = 0;i <=rowcount;i++)
{
   for(j=0;j<=colcount;j++)
   {
      if (user1==selenium.gettable("//@[id=dldl/tbody" +i "td"+j))
      {
         system.out.println(user1  + "Inserted");
         break;
      }
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried with the same solution you provide. But xpath is not taking i(counter) instead if you use a static row no it works. Any other possible solution

Answer (score 1):

Get the number of rows using:

`int noOfRowsInTable = selenium.getXpathCount("//table[@id='TableId']//tr");`

If the UserName you want to get is at fixed position, let's say at 2nd position, then for each row iterate as given below:

`selenium.getText("xpath=//table[@id='TableId']//tr//td[1]");`

**Note:** we can find the number of columns in that table using same procedure

`int noOfColumnsInTable = selenium.getXpathCount("//table[@id='TableId']//tr//td");`

Answer (score 0):

Generically, something like this?

```
table = @browser.table(:id,'tableID')
table.rows.each do |row|
    # perform row operations here
    row.cells.each do |cell|
        # do cell operations here
   end
end
```